# How to add a menu item to the front page of a site?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm looking for a bit of help with a site that I'm working on that uses WordPress as a CMS. Basically, I am attempting to add a menu item called 'Mood Boards' to the [front page](http://yourdreamshaadi.co.uk) of this site, so that when a user hovers over 'What's Hot' the dropdown menu includes a Mood Boards link.

Since I'm using a custom theme, a lot of the functionality has been stripped from the WordPress back end meaning that I have to hack the code in order to add this item to the nav. I have already added the custom post type to WordPress which is appearing in the back end menu.

My main problem is I'm not sure which file directly handles the addition of menu items to the front end, I believe it is nav-menu.php (see below) which uses a Walker to traverse the tree and add menu items.

```
        <?php
/**
 * Navigation Menu functions
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Nav_Menus
 * @since 3.0.0
 */

/**
 * Returns a navigation menu object.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @uses get_term
 * @uses get_term_by
 *
 * @param string $menu Menu id, slug or name
 * @return mixed false if $menu param isn't supplied or term does not exist, menu object if successful.
 */
function wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu ) {
    if ( ! $menu )
        return false;

    $menu_obj = get_term( $menu, 'nav_menu' );

    if ( ! $menu_obj )
        $menu_obj = get_term_by( 'slug', $menu, 'nav_menu' );

    if ( ! $menu_obj )
        $menu_obj = get_term_by( 'name', $menu, 'nav_menu' );

    if ( ! $menu_obj )
        $menu_obj = false;

    return $menu_obj;
}

/**
 * Check if the given ID is a navigation menu.
 *
 * Returns true if it is; false otherwise.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param int|string $menu The menu to check (id, slug, or name)
 * @return bool Whether the menu exists.
 */
function is_nav_menu( $menu ) {
    if ( ! $menu )
        return false;

    $menu_obj = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu );

    if (
        $menu_obj &&
        ! is_wp_error( $menu_obj ) &&
        ! empty( $menu_obj->taxonomy ) &&
        'nav_menu' == $menu_obj->taxonomy
    )
        return true;

    return false;
}

/**
 * Register navigation menus for a theme.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param array $locations Associative array of menu location identifiers (like a slug) and descriptive text.
 */
function register_nav_menus( $locations = array() ) {
    global $_wp_registered_nav_menus;

    add_theme_support( 'menus' );

    $_wp_registered_nav_menus = array_merge( (array) $_wp_registered_nav_menus, $locations );
}

/**
 * Unregisters a navigation menu for a theme.
 *
 * @param array $location the menu location identifier
 *
 * @return bool True on success, false on failure.
 */
function unregister_nav_menu( $location ) {
    global $_wp_registered_nav_menus;

    if ( is_array( $_wp_registered_nav_menus ) && isset( $_wp_registered_nav_menus[$location] ) ) {
        unset( $_wp_registered_nav_menus[$location] );
        if ( empty( $_wp_registered_nav_menus ) ) {
            _remove_theme_support( 'menus' );
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Register a navigation menu for a theme.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param string $location Menu location identifier, like a slug.
 * @param string $description Menu location descriptive text.
 */
function register_nav_menu( $location, $description ) {
    register_nav_menus( array( $location => $description ) );
}
/**
 * Returns an array of all registered navigation menus in a theme
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @return array
 */
function get_registered_nav_menus() {
    global $_wp_registered_nav_menus;
    if ( isset( $_wp_registered_nav_menus ) )
        return $_wp_registered_nav_menus;
    return array();
}

/**
 * Returns an array with the registered navigation menu locations and the menu assigned to it
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @return array
 */

function get_nav_menu_locations() {
    $locations = get_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations' );
    return ( is_array( $locations ) ) ? $locations : array();
}

/**
 * Whether a registered nav menu location has a menu assigned to it.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @param string $location Menu location identifier.
 * @return bool Whether location has a menu.
 */
function has_nav_menu( $location ) {
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    return ( ! empty( $locations[ $location ] ) );
}

/**
 * Determine whether the given ID is a nav menu item.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param int $menu_item_id The ID of the potential nav menu item.
 * @return bool Whether the given ID is that of a nav menu item.
 */
function is_nav_menu_item( $menu_item_id = 0 ) {
    return ( ! is_wp_error( $menu_item_id ) && ( 'nav_menu_item' == get_post_type( $menu_item_id ) ) );
}

/**
 * Create a Navigation Menu.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param string $menu_name Menu Name
 * @return mixed Menu object on success|WP_Error on failure
 */
function wp_create_nav_menu( $menu_name ) {
    return wp_update_nav_menu_object( 0, array( 'menu-name' => $menu_name ) );
}

/**
 * Delete a Navigation Menu.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param string $menu name|id|slug
 * @return mixed Menu object on success|WP_Error on failure
 */
function wp_delete_nav_menu( $menu ) {
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu );
    if ( ! $menu )
        return false;

    $menu_objects = get_objects_in_term( $menu->term_id, 'nav_menu' );
    if ( ! empty( $menu_objects ) ) {
        foreach ( $menu_objects as $item ) {
            wp_delete_post( $item );
        }
    }

    $result = wp_delete_term( $menu->term_id, 'nav_menu' );

    // Remove this menu from any locations.
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    foreach ( $locations as $location => $menu_id ) {
        if ( $menu_id == $menu->term_id )
            $locations[ $location ] = 0;
    }
    set_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations', $locations );

    if ( $result && !is_wp_error($result) )

        /**
         * Fires after a navigation menu has been successfully deleted.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param int $term_id ID of the deleted menu.
         */
        do_action( 'wp_delete_nav_menu', $menu->term_id );

    return $result;
}

/**
 * Save the properties of a menu or create a new menu with those properties.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param int $menu_id The ID of the menu or "0" to create a new menu.
 * @param array $menu_data The array of menu data.
 * @return int|WP_Error object The menu's ID or WP_Error object.
 */
function wp_update_nav_menu_object( $menu_id = 0, $menu_data = array() ) {
    $menu_id = (int) $menu_id;

    $_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu_id );

    $args = array(
        'description' => ( isset( $menu_data['description'] ) ? $menu_data['description']  : '' ),
        'name'        => ( isset( $menu_data['menu-name']   ) ? $menu_data['menu-name']    : '' ),
        'parent'      => ( isset( $menu_data['parent']      ) ? (int) $menu_data['parent'] : 0  ),
        'slug'        => null,
    );

    // double-check that we're not going to have one menu take the name of another
    $_possible_existing = get_term_by( 'name', $menu_data['menu-name'], 'nav_menu' );
    if (
        $_possible_existing &&
        ! is_wp_error( $_possible_existing ) &&
        isset( $_possible_existing->term_id ) &&
        $_possible_existing->term_id != $menu_id
    )
        return new WP_Error( 'menu_exists', sprintf( __('The menu name <strong>%s</strong> conflicts with another menu name. Please try another.'), esc_html( $menu_data['menu-name'] ) ) );

    // menu doesn't already exist, so create a new menu
    if ( ! $_menu || is_wp_error( $_menu ) ) {
        $menu_exists = get_term_by( 'name', $menu_data['menu-name'], 'nav_menu' );

        if ( $menu_exists )
            return new WP_Error( 'menu_exists', sprintf( __('The menu name <strong>%s</strong> conflicts with another menu name. Please try another.'), esc_html( $menu_data['menu-name'] ) ) );

        $_menu = wp_insert_term( $menu_data['menu-name'], 'nav_menu', $args );

        if ( is_wp_error( $_menu ) )
            return $_menu;

        /**
         * Fires after a navigation menu is successfully created.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param int   $term_id   ID of the new menu.
         * @param array $menu_data An array of menu data.
         */
        do_action( 'wp_create_nav_menu', $_menu['term_id'], $menu_data );

        return (int) $_menu['term_id'];
    }

    if ( ! $_menu || ! isset( $_menu->term_id ) )
        return 0;

    $menu_id = (int) $_menu->term_id;

    $update_response = wp_update_term( $menu_id, 'nav_menu', $args );

    if ( is_wp_error( $update_response ) )
        return $update_response;

    /**
     * Fires after a navigation menu has been successfully updated.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param int   $menu_id   ID of the updated menu.
     * @param array $menu_data An array of menu data.
     */
    do_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu', $menu_id, $menu_data );
    return $menu_id;
}

/**
 * Save the properties of a menu item or create a new one.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param int $menu_id The ID of the menu. Required. If "0", makes the menu item a draft orphan.
 * @param int $menu_item_db_id The ID of the menu item. If "0", creates a new menu item.
 * @param array $menu_item_data The menu item's data.
 * @return int|WP_Error The menu item's database ID or WP_Error object on failure.
 */
function wp_update_nav_menu_item( $menu_id = 0, $menu_item_db_id = 0, $menu_item_data = array() ) {
    $menu_id = (int) $menu_id;
    $menu_item_db_id = (int) $menu_item_db_id;

    // make sure that we don't convert non-nav_menu_item objects into nav_menu_item objects
    if ( ! empty( $menu_item_db_id ) && ! is_nav_menu_item( $menu_item_db_id ) )
        return new WP_Error( 'update_nav_menu_item_failed', __( 'The given object ID is not that of a menu item.' ) );

    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu_id );

    if ( ! $menu && 0 !== $menu_id ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_menu_id', __( 'Invalid menu ID.' ) );
    }

    if ( is_wp_error( $menu ) ) {
        return $menu;
    }

    $defaults = array(
        'menu-item-db-id' => $menu_item_db_id,
        'menu-item-object-id' => 0,
        'menu-item-object' => '',
        'menu-item-parent-id' => 0,
        'menu-item-position' => 0,
        'menu-item-type' => 'custom',
        'menu-item-title' => '',
        'menu-item-url' => '',
        'menu-item-description' => '',
        'menu-item-attr-title' => '',
        'menu-item-target' => '',
        'menu-item-classes' => '',
        'menu-item-xfn' => '',
        'menu-item-status' => '',
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args( $menu_item_data, $defaults );

    if ( 0 == $menu_id ) {
        $args['menu-item-position'] = 1;
    } elseif ( 0 == (int) $args['menu-item-position'] ) {
        $menu_items = 0 == $menu_id ? array() : (array) wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu_id, array( 'post_status' => 'publish,draft' ) );
        $last_item = array_pop( $menu_items );
        $args['menu-item-position'] = ( $last_item && isset( $last_item->menu_order ) ) ? 1 + $last_item->menu_order : count( $menu_items );
    }

    $original_parent = 0 < $menu_item_db_id ? get_post_field( 'post_parent', $menu_item_db_id ) : 0;

    if ( 'custom' != $args['menu-item-type'] ) {
        /* if non-custom menu item, then:
            * use original object's URL
            * blank default title to sync with original object's
        */

        $args['menu-item-url'] = '';

        $original_title = '';
        if ( 'taxonomy' == $args['menu-item-type'] ) {
            $original_parent = get_term_field( 'parent', $args['menu-item-object-id'], $args['menu-item-object'], 'raw' );
            $original_title = get_term_field( 'name', $args['menu-item-object-id'], $args['menu-item-object'], 'raw' );
        } elseif ( 'post_type' == $args['menu-item-type'] ) {

            $original_object = get_post( $args['menu-item-object-id'] );
            $original_parent = (int) $original_object->post_parent;
            $original_title = $original_object->post_title;
        }

        if ( $args['menu-item-title'] == $original_title )
            $args['menu-item-title'] = '';

        // hack to get wp to create a post object when too many properties are empty
        if ( '' ==  $args['menu-item-title'] && '' == $args['menu-item-description'] )
            $args['menu-item-description'] = ' ';
    }

    // Populate the menu item object
    $post = array(
        'menu_order' => $args['menu-item-position'],
        'ping_status' => 0,
        'post_content' => $args['menu-item-description'],
        'post_excerpt' => $args['menu-item-attr-title'],
        'post_parent' => $original_parent,
        'post_title' => $args['menu-item-title'],
        'post_type' => 'nav_menu_item',
    );

    $update = 0 != $menu_item_db_id;

    // New menu item. Default is draft status
    if ( ! $update ) {
        $post['ID'] = 0;
        $post['post_status'] = 'publish' == $args['menu-item-status'] ? 'publish' : 'draft';
        $menu_item_db_id = wp_insert_post( $post );
        if ( ! $menu_item_db_id || is_wp_error( $menu_item_db_id ) )
            return $menu_item_db_id;
    }

    // Associate the menu item with the menu term
    // Only set the menu term if it isn't set to avoid unnecessary wp_get_object_terms()
     if ( $menu_id && ( ! $update || ! is_object_in_term( $menu_item_db_id, 'nav_menu', (int) $menu->term_id ) ) ) {
        wp_set_object_terms( $menu_item_db_id, array( $menu->term_id ), 'nav_menu' );
    }

    if ( 'custom' == $args['menu-item-type'] ) {
        $args['menu-item-object-id'] = $menu_item_db_id;
        $args['menu-item-object'] = 'custom';
    }

    $menu_item_db_id = (int) $menu_item_db_id;

    update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_type', sanitize_key($args['menu-item-type']) );
    update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', strval( (int) $args['menu-item-parent-id'] ) );
    update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_object_id', strval( (int) $args['menu-item-object-id'] ) );
    update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_object', sanitize_key($args['menu-item-object']) );
    update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_target', sanitize_key($args['menu-item-target']) );

    $args['menu-item-classes'] = array_map( 'sanitize_html_class', explode( ' ', $args['menu-item-classes'] ) );
    $args['menu-item-xfn'] = implode( ' ', array_map( 'sanitize_html_class', explode( ' ', $args['menu-item-xfn'] ) ) );
    update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_classes', $args['menu-item-classes'] );
    update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_xfn', $args['menu-item-xfn'] );
    update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_url', esc_url_raw($args['menu-item-url']) );

    if ( 0 == $menu_id )
        update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_orphaned', (string) time() );
    elseif ( get_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_orphaned' ) )
        delete_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_orphaned' );

    // Update existing menu item. Default is publish status
    if ( $update ) {
        $post['ID'] = $menu_item_db_id;
        $post['post_status'] = 'draft' == $args['menu-item-status'] ? 'draft' : 'publish';
        wp_update_post( $post );
    }

    /**
     * Fires after a navigation menu item has been updated.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see wp_update_nav_menu_items()
     *
     * @param int   $menu_id         ID of the updated menu.
     * @param int   $menu_item_db_id ID of the updated menu item.
     * @param array $args            An array of arguments used to update a menu item.
     */
    do_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu_item', $menu_id, $menu_item_db_id, $args );

    return $menu_item_db_id;
}

/**
 * Returns all navigation menu objects.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param array $args Array of arguments passed on to get_terms().
 * @return array menu objects
 */
function wp_get_nav_menus( $args = array() ) {
    $defaults = array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'orderby' => 'none' );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    /**
     * Filter the navigation menu objects being returned.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see get_terms()
     *
     * @param array $menus An array of menu objects.
     * @param array $args  An array of arguments used to retrieve menu objects.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'wp_get_nav_menus', get_terms( 'nav_menu',  $args), $args );
}

/**
 * Sort menu items by the desired key.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @access private
 *
 * @param object $a The first object to compare
 * @param object $b The second object to compare
 * @return int -1, 0, or 1 if $a is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than $b.
 */
function _sort_nav_menu_items( $a, $b ) {
    global $_menu_item_sort_prop;

    if ( empty( $_menu_item_sort_prop ) )
        return 0;

    if ( ! isset( $a->$_menu_item_sort_prop ) || ! isset( $b->$_menu_item_sort_prop ) )
        return 0;

    $_a = (int) $a->$_menu_item_sort_prop;
    $_b = (int) $b->$_menu_item_sort_prop;

    if ( $a->$_menu_item_sort_prop == $b->$_menu_item_sort_prop )
        return 0;
    elseif ( $_a == $a->$_menu_item_sort_prop && $_b == $b->$_menu_item_sort_prop )
        return $_a < $_b ? -1 : 1;
    else
        return strcmp( $a->$_menu_item_sort_prop, $b->$_menu_item_sort_prop );
}

/**
 * Returns if a menu item is valid. Bug #13958
 *
 * @since 3.2.0
 * @access private
 *
 * @param object $menu_item The menu item to check
 * @return bool false if invalid, else true.
 */
function _is_valid_nav_menu_item( $item ) {
    if ( ! empty( $item->_invalid ) )
        return false;

    return true;
}

/**
 * Returns all menu items of a navigation menu.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param string $menu menu name, id, or slug
 * @param string $args
 * @return mixed $items array of menu items, else false.
 */
function wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu, $args = array() ) {
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu );

    if ( ! $menu )
        return false;

    static $fetched = array();

    $items = get_objects_in_term( $menu->term_id, 'nav_menu' );

    if ( empty( $items ) )
        return $items;

    $defaults = array( 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'post_type' => 'nav_menu_item',
        'post_status' => 'publish', 'output' => ARRAY_A, 'output_key' => 'menu_order', 'nopaging' => true );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    if ( count( $items ) > 1 )
        $args['include'] = implode( ',', $items );
    else
        $args['include'] = $items[0];

    $items = get_posts( $args );

    if ( is_wp_error( $items ) || ! is_array( $items ) )
        return false;

    // Get all posts and terms at once to prime the caches
    if ( empty( $fetched[$menu->term_id] ) || wp_using_ext_object_cache() ) {
        $fetched[$menu->term_id] = true;
        $posts = array();
        $terms = array();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $object_id = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );
            $object    = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_object',    true );
            $type      = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_type',      true );

            if ( 'post_type' == $type )
                $posts[$object][] = $object_id;
            elseif ( 'taxonomy' == $type)
                $terms[$object][] = $object_id;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
            foreach ( array_keys($posts) as $post_type ) {
                get_posts( array('post__in' => $posts[$post_type], 'post_type' => $post_type, 'nopaging' => true, 'update_post_term_cache' => false) );
            }
        }
        unset($posts);

        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
            foreach ( array_keys($terms) as $taxonomy ) {
                get_terms($taxonomy, array('include' => $terms[$taxonomy]) );
            }
        }
        unset($terms);
    }

    $items = array_map( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', $items );

    if ( ! is_admin() ) // Remove invalid items only in frontend
        $items = array_filter( $items, '_is_valid_nav_menu_item' );

    if ( ARRAY_A == $args['output'] ) {
        $GLOBALS['_menu_item_sort_prop'] = $args['output_key'];
        usort($items, '_sort_nav_menu_items');
        $i = 1;
        foreach( $items as $k => $item ) {
            $items[$k]->$args['output_key'] = $i++;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Filter the navigation menu items being returned.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param array  $items An array of menu item post objects.
     * @param object $menu  The menu object.
     * @param array  $args  An array of arguments used to retrieve menu item objects.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items',  $items, $menu, $args );
}

/**
 * Decorates a menu item object with the shared navigation menu item properties.
 *
 * Properties:
 * - db_id:         The DB ID of this item as a nav_menu_item object, if it exists (0 if it doesn't exist).
 * - object_id:     The DB ID of the original object this menu item represents, e.g. ID for posts and term_id for categories.
 * - type:      The family of objects originally represented, such as "post_type" or "taxonomy."
 * - object:        The type of object originally represented, such as "category," "post", or "attachment."
 * - type_label:    The singular label used to describe this type of menu item.
 * - post_parent:   The DB ID of the original object's parent object, if any (0 otherwise).
 * - menu_item_parent:  The DB ID of the nav_menu_item that is this item's menu parent, if any. 0 otherwise.
 * - url:       The URL to which this menu item points.
 * - title:     The title of this menu item.
 * - target:        The target attribute of the link element for this menu item.
 * - attr_title:    The title attribute of the link element for this menu item.
 * - classes:       The array of class attribute values for the link element of this menu item.
 * - xfn:       The XFN relationship expressed in the link of this menu item.
 * - description:   The description of this menu item.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param object $menu_item The menu item to modify.
 * @return object $menu_item The menu item with standard menu item properties.
 */
function wp_setup_nav_menu_item( $menu_item ) {
    if ( isset( $menu_item->post_type ) ) {
        if ( 'nav_menu_item' == $menu_item->post_type ) {
            $menu_item->db_id = (int) $menu_item->ID;
            $menu_item->menu_item_parent = empty( $menu_item->menu_item_parent ) ? get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', true ) : $menu_item->menu_item_parent;
            $menu_item->object_id = empty( $menu_item->object_id ) ? get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true ) : $menu_item->object_id;
            $menu_item->object = empty( $menu_item->object ) ? get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_object', true ) : $menu_item->object;
            $menu_item->type = empty( $menu_item->type ) ? get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_type', true ) : $menu_item->type;

            if ( 'post_type' == $menu_item->type ) {
                $object = get_post_type_object( $menu_item->object );
                if ( $object ) {
                    $menu_item->type_label = $object->labels->singular_name;
                } else {
                    $menu_item->type_label = $menu_item->object;
                    $menu_item->_invalid = true;
                }

                $menu_item->url = get_permalink( $menu_item->object_id );

                $original_object = get_post( $menu_item->object_id );
                $original_title = $original_object->post_title;
                $menu_item->title = '' == $menu_item->post_title ? $original_title : $menu_item->post_title;

            } elseif ( 'taxonomy' == $menu_item->type ) {
                $object = get_taxonomy( $menu_item->object );
                if ( $object ) {
                    $menu_item->type_label = $object->labels->singular_name;
                } else {
                    $menu_item->type_label = $menu_item->object;
                    $menu_item->_invalid = true;
                }

                $term_url = get_term_link( (int) $menu_item->object_id, $menu_item->object );
                $menu_item->url = !is_wp_error( $term_url ) ? $term_url : '';

                $original_title = get_term_field( 'name', $menu_item->object_id, $menu_item->object, 'raw' );
                if ( is_wp_error( $original_title ) )
                    $original_title = false;
                $menu_item->title = '' == $menu_item->post_title ? $original_title : $menu_item->post_title;

            } else {
                $menu_item->type_label = __('Custom');
                $menu_item->title = $menu_item->post_title;
                $menu_item->url = empty( $menu_item->url ) ? get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_url', true ) : $menu_item->url;
            }

            $menu_item->target = empty( $menu_item->target ) ? get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_target', true ) : $menu_item->target;

            /**
             * Filter a navigation menu item's title attribute.
             *
             * @since 3.0.0
             *
             * @param string $item_title The menu item title attribute.
             */
            $menu_item->attr_title = empty( $menu_item->attr_title ) ? apply_filters( 'nav_menu_attr_title', $menu_item->post_excerpt ) : $menu_item->attr_title;

            if ( empty( $menu_item->description ) ) {
                /**
                 * Filter a navigation menu item's description.
                 *
                 * @since 3.0.0
                 *
                 * @param string $description The menu item description.
                 */
                $menu_item->description = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_description', wp_trim_words( $menu_item->post_content, 200 ) );
            }

            $menu_item->classes = empty( $menu_item->classes ) ? (array) get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_classes', true ) : $menu_item->classes;
            $menu_item->xfn = empty( $menu_item->xfn ) ? get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_xfn', true ) : $menu_item->xfn;
        } else {
            $menu_item->db_id = 0;
            $menu_item->menu_item_parent = 0;
            $menu_item->object_id = (int) $menu_item->ID;
            $menu_item->type = 'post_type';

            $object = get_post_type_object( $menu_item->post_type );
            $menu_item->object = $object->name;
            $menu_item->type_label = $object->labels->singular_name;

            if ( '' === $menu_item->post_title )
                $menu_item->post_title = sprintf( __( '#%d (no title)' ), $menu_item->ID );

            $menu_item->title = $menu_item->post_title;
            $menu_item->url = get_permalink( $menu_item->ID );
            $menu_item->target = '';

            /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/nav-menu.php */
            $menu_item->attr_title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_attr_title', '' );

            /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/nav-menu.php */
            $menu_item->description = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_description', '' );
            $menu_item->classes = array();
            $menu_item->xfn = '';
        }
    } elseif ( isset( $menu_item->taxonomy ) ) {
        $menu_item->ID = $menu_item->term_id;
        $menu_item->db_id = 0;
        $menu_item->menu_item_parent = 0;
        $menu_item->object_id = (int) $menu_item->term_id;
        $menu_item->post_parent = (int) $menu_item->parent;
        $menu_item->type = 'taxonomy';

        $object = get_taxonomy( $menu_item->taxonomy );
        $menu_item->object = $object->name;
        $menu_item->type_label = $object->labels->singular_name;

        $menu_item->title = $menu_item->name;
        $menu_item->url = get_term_link( $menu_item, $menu_item->taxonomy );
        $menu_item->target = '';
        $menu_item->attr_title = '';
        $menu_item->description = get_term_field( 'description', $menu_item->term_id, $menu_item->taxonomy );
        $menu_item->classes = array();
        $menu_item->xfn = '';

    }

    /**
     * Filter a navigation menu item object.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param object $menu_item The menu item object.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', $menu_item );
}
```

Comment: why you are not adding menu item from backend? It gives facility to add custom menu item with custom link.

Comment: where? As I said in the question due to using a custom theme, this back end functionality seems to have been stripped. Although I'm al l ears if you know of a secret location for it.

Comment: You've posted far too much code here, please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the section about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Write below code in theme's `function.php` file :-

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 10, 2 );

function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {

    if ($args->theme_location == 'primary') {

        $items .= '<li>Show whatever</li>';

    }

    return $items;

}
```

Comment: I'm a bit unsure of this as well as in functions.php all there is is a bunch of includes to template parts, none of which contain add_filters for menu items... Will give it a go though

Comment: Do you have functions.php file in your theme folder ?

Comment: Indeedy I do, however it just locates templates from a /lib folder.

Comment: May I know your path to your theme folder (which is currently activated) ?

Comment: /wp-content/themes/custom-theme-parent

Comment: so in custom-theme-parent folder, do you have any file called functions.php ? If yes, then, you can add the code in that file.